Is the ToBase64Transform code sample wrong?
There's a code sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.tobase64transform
I believe the code sample is wrong.
I tried copy-pasting it in VS2022, in a project with the main cs file named members.cs
It says it doesn't find members.cs in the debug folder along with the executable. I copied members.cs there. It created members.enc but it's empty, 0 bytes. I expected some encrypted output. I don't fully understand C# yet but if there's something wrong with the code, please report it to Microsoft. The more I learn, the more confused I am.
Try it yourself and tell me who's wrong here, it's hard to learn when you don't trust the learning material...

Perform a Clean build which force all the source code to rebuild.  The cs file needs to be in the main project folder with all the other cs files (not in the bin folder).  The compiler will create obj files from the source (put in the obj folder) and then link all the obj files to create the executable and place in the bin folder.

Clean Solution + Rebuild solution doesn't help, that's why I believe the source code provided by Microsoft may be wrong, can someone confirm?

Try to do some basic debugging on the directory from the code. Not finding files is often a problem caused by not being in the correct working directory. Just print it out, and make sure your member.cs is in the correct folder.

I suspect the working directory is the directory of the compiled output. If you added member.cs in the project directory, then you should realize it's like some kind of resource, not an actual file to compile from the project. You can right-click on the file and in some kind of properties popup, select "Copy" instead of compile or whatever, that should copy the file in the output directory when you compile your project. Or, simply but the file in the output directory manually.

Did that, it finds the members.cs, it loads all its bytes and i guess it just creates the new file and writes nothing to it

This is a perfectly valid question. The linked sample from Microsoft does indeed appear to be incorrect.
The first problem is that the Members.cs file needs to have Copy to Output Directory set to Copy always, which is not stated in the article. This will allow the executing code to see the Members.cs file in the output folder.
The second problem is that ToBase64Transform.CanTransformMultipleBlocks always returns true, so the check if (!base64Transform.CanTransformMultipleBlocks) always fails, meaning that nothing is ever written to the output file (i.e. members.enc always has zero bytes).
If this check is removed or inverted, the code still fails to run correctly. It looks like the length of the input block (always 3 bytes or fewer) is not being passed correctly.
Changing this:
base64Transform.TransformBlock(
    inputBytes,
    inputOffset,
    inputBytes.Length - inputOffset,
    outputBytes,
    0);

to this:
base64Transform.TransformBlock(
    inputBytes,
    inputOffset,
    Math.Min(3, inputBytes.Length - inputOffset),
    outputBytes,
    0);

allows the code to run and generate an output file (members.enc) of a sensible size (5 KB).
I cannot vouch for the rest of the code or the validity of this file, but this should be enough to get you closer and allow you to verify the output.

Thank youu!! This really answers my question, I was suspecting "CanTransformMultipleBlocks" and the parameters in "TransformBlock" too, but I needed some reassurance that Microsoft is not always right and that I should be more skeptical about every code I encounter. I tried your suggestions and at least I got an output. I'll keep learning.

There's a link to "Open a documentation issue" at the bottom of that doc page, if you wanted to let Microsoft know how to fix it.

@AndrewMorton thank you, opened github issue
https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/10176
